# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError after system is running for multiple hours

Tags: java, reflection, virtual-machine, nosuchmethoderror

Assume a public Class A

```
public class A {

    public boolean test(Object a) {
        return true;
    }

}
```

and let this method invoke via

```
java.lang.Class.forName("A").getMethod(test, Object.class).invoke(new A(), new Object());
```

This routine works during Application's runtime 24/7 but seems to fail non-deterministic. It throws a NoSuchMethodError.

Do you have any idea, why this method will fail from one timepoint to another?

We use the java 8 version from open jdk project and run the application in SUSE enterprise 14.0.4 and this server was up and running without any hint of interruption.

After restarting the application without any changes on the JAR the function invocation works perfectly fine again.

Comment: Such error depends on invocation actually: do you invoke from multiple parallel threads or maybe from different classloaders?  Could you provide full error trace?

Comment: You could get this method once at sever startup `Method test = java.lang.Class.forName("A").getMethod(test, Object.class)` and then just use reference to it, then it would not depend on invocation anymore. (expect accessibility rights, this can be solved too by using MethodHandles instead)